# AngularJs directive to offer suggestions for misspelled emails?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to reduce bounce rates of emails sent from the website I am building. After looking at the list of registered users I have noticed that quite often people misspell domain on email, like *user@gmai.com* or *user@gmail.con*

Other than somehow tying MX lookup and AngularJs, what are my options for verifying that email address is correct before wasting a bounce on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [Mailcheck.js on Github](https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck) which does exactly what I want by providing suggestion like "Did you mean *user@gmail.com*?"

However, library is for plain Javascript / jQuery. I needed AngularJs wrapper so I slightly modified [angular-mailcheck](https://github.com/simison/angular-mailcheck) here is resulting directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @ngdoc directive
     * @name mailcheck.directive:mailcheck
     * @description
     * Angular wrapper for Mailcheck.js
     */
    function mailcheckDirective($compile, $sce) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: false,
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                //Mailcheck.defaultDomains.push('yandex.ru', 'rambler.ru', 'bk.ru', 'ukr.net', 'list.ru', 'inbox.ru', 'yandex.ua', 'ya.ru', 'i.ua', 'inbox.lv', 'mail.ua', 'yandex.com', 'abv.bg', 'icloud.com', 'meta.ua', 'tut.by', 'rediffmail.com');
                Mailcheck.defaultTopLevelDomains.push('com.id', 'com.ph', 'com.br', 'com.vn', 'com.in');

                // Limit to input element of specific types
                var inputTypes = /text|email/i;
                if (el[0].nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
                    throw new Error('angular-mailcheck is limited to input elements');
                }
                if (!inputTypes.test(attrs.type)) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid input type for angular-mailcheck: ' + attrs.type);
                }

                scope.suggestion = false;
                scope.bugmenot = false;

                // Compiled template
                if (attrs.mailcheck !== "notemplate") {
                    var template = $compile('<div class="help-block mailcheck" ng-show="suggestion && !bugmenot">Did you mean <a ng-bind="suggestion" ng-click="useSuggestion()"></a>? <a ng-click="suggestion=false;bugmenot=true">Nope.</a></div>')(scope);
                    el.after(template);
                }

                el.bind('input', function () {
                    scope.suggestion = false;
                })
                .bind('blur', function () {
                    el.mailcheck({
                        suggested: function (element, suggestion) {
                            scope.suggestion = suggestion.full;
                            scope.$apply();
                        },
                        empty: function (element) {
                            scope.suggestion = false;
                        }
                    });
                });

                scope.useSuggestion = function () {
                    el.val(scope.suggestion);
                    scope.suggestion = false;
                };

            }
        };
    }

    angular
      .module('angular-mailcheck', [])
      .directive('mailcheck', mailcheckDirective);

    mailcheckDirective.$inject = ['$compile', '$sce'];

})();
```

Once directive is part of solution it can be used like this in HTML:

```
<input mailcheck="notemplate" />
<small class="mailcheck" ng-show="suggestion && !bugmenot">
    <span>Did you mean</span> <a ng-bind="suggestion" ng-click="useSuggestion()"></a>?
    <a ng-click="suggestion=false;bugmenot=true">Nope</a>.
</small>
```

If you don't need to customize mailcheck block in HTML you can user `mailcheck=""` attribute instead of `mailcheck="notemplate"`.

Comment: thank you so much for this! PS if anyone needs a react version, there is one available https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mailcheck